# Hide content only for Gmail users

Tags: gmail, conditional-statements, html-email, email-templates

I'm writing email templates and I need to HIDE a piece of content for Gmail users.

There exists [an easy way to SHOW content only to Gmail users] but as you will notice, this isn't reversible as it uses the fact that Gmail ignores `display:none;`.

There's also a way to show/hide content for Outlook + IE users (using conditional HTML statements like `<!–[if gte mso 9]> <![endif]–>`), but the same method doesn't seem to exist for Gmail or Yahoo or anything else.

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: if `{display: none;}` doesn't work try `{display: none !important;}` or  `{height: 0; width: 0; overflow: hidden; opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; position: absolute;}`

Comment: Hi Asfan, I don't understand how this code relates to hiding content only for Gmail users. You are referring to the code in my question which is designed to do the opposite of what I want :(

Comment: You told that `There exists [an easy way to SHOW content only to Gmail users]`. So, I thought you already know that how to target particular section and hide it in Gmail.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my answer. I dont think you tested the code or even did a search around the web to see how it works. I have been using this method to hide elements in Desktop and mobile. Hope you find the answer you were looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of HTML conditional statements / expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57973654/list-of-html-conditional-statements-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

Gmail.com will strip all of your CSS located in the header. The only options to hide something is inline styling like `display:none !important`, but then it will be gone for email client.

So the answer to your question is: No, its not possible.